# PostgreSQL : converting jsonb to columns

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Having issue with transforming jsonb to desired table type, any help would be appreciated.

**My jsonb is**

```
{"instances": [{"code": "12345"}, {"code": "6789"}, {"code": "54321"}]
```

I want to transform it to:

```
code1      code2     code3
12345      6789      54321
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you have 5000 codes inside the array?

Comment: You can't return an arbitrary number of columns in a SQL query

Comment: I can have 3 columns max in my context

Answer (score 0):

One limitation of SQL is that the number of columns (and their data types) of a query must be known to the database *before* the query is executed. So there is no way you can get a dynamic query that returns 3 columns today and 42 tomorrow.

If you have a static number of array elements (or at least an upper limit), you can use the following:

```
select the_column -> 'instances' -> 0 ->> 'code' as code_1, 
       the_column -> 'instances' -> 1 ->> 'code' as code_2, 
       the_column -> 'instances' -> 2 ->> 'code' as code_3
from the_table;
```

you can simplify that a bit by using a derived table:

```
select inst -> 0 ->> 'code' as code_1, 
       inst -> 1 ->> 'code' as code_2, 
       inst -> 2 ->> 'code' as code_3
from (
  select the_column -> 'instances' as inst
  from the_table
) t
```